# Children webservice geonames

Tags: java, geonames

I'm using java client of geonames and the default maxRows of WebService.children is 200. How I change this to get all children (in some cases there's more than 200)?

Comment: Is this for the __free__ or __premium__ version?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot that. It is the free version =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most WebServices that offer both a **free** and a **premium** service it is likely that the `WebService.children` call that you are making has an upper limit of 200 results.

Looking at the terms of their [premium web services](http://www.geonames.org/commercial-webservices.html) it states:

> Advantages of the 'Premium Webservices' over the 'free webservice'
>
> - Higher max limits for a couple of parameter like maxRows or startRow